# Mongod index - memory and file

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have a collection with 10 million documents each having four simple text fields. It takes about 5 minutes for Mongo to build an index on a field for the first time (i.e. when I run an ensureIndex command from Mongo shell).

I am aware that Mongo indexes are B-tree data structures maintained in the memory. But when I shutdown and restart the mongod, the indexes are in action instantaneously (i.e.) Queries that are run immediately after server start up,  makes use of the index.

Would like to know:
1. When these indexes are synced with a file on the disk ?
2. When will such indexes will be loaded back in memory if mongod is restarted ?

Mongo builts an index in the following two stages (one can observe this in mongod log). Any idea what is done in each of these stages.
1. External sort progress
2. Btree bottom up progress

Answer (score 1):

Indexes are managed the same way the collections themselves are: They are stored on disk, but (hopefully, if you have enough RAM), cached in memory.

They will be loaded into memory (page-by-page, not all at once) when you access them. And they will stay in memory until you need the memory for something else. This is managed by a caching strategy that is supposed to keep the most frequently accessed portions of your database in memory.